# Openedge form - avoid the message Press space bar to continue

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm writing a program to accept input from the user.  I display some background text in a frame, then use an overlay frame to prompt for input.  In my simple example below I get the message "Press space bar to continue" before the prompt-for is run.

What can I do do skip seeing that message?

```
/* Background */
def var dLines as char format "x(78)" extent 20 no-undo.

dLines[1] = "Password:".
dLines[2] = "".
dLines[3] = "Scan/key password".

form
  dLines[1]  skip
  dLines[2]  skip
  dLines[3]
  with frame fLabel no-labels no-box row 1 column 1 screen-io.

display
  dLines[1]
  dLines[2]
  dLines[3]
  with frame fLabel screen-io.


/* Prompt for data */
def var dString as char no-undo.

form
  dString format "x(60)"
  with frame cPrompt14 overlay no-labels no-box row 1 column 12 screen-io.

/*** This is where I get the "Press space bar to continue" message ***/ 
prompt-for
  dString
  with frame cPrompt14.

assign dString.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are prompted to press the space bar in CHUI when the view port is full. You can avoid this with `PAUSE 0 BEFORE-HIDE NO-MESSAGE.`